# Why could not load data from Adapter into JSONStore?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

```
function getListPhoneNumbers() {

    var data = {listContacts:[{name:'Ho Cong Vi',number:'12345666'},{name:'hcv',number:'6543218'}]};

    WL.Logger.info('Data:'+JSON.stringify(data));
    return data;
}

function addListPhoneNumber(data) {

    WL.Logger.debug('Add Data to JSONStore: ' + data);
    return;
}

function updateListPhoneNumber(data) {

    WL.Logger.debug('Updata Data from JSONStore: ' + data);
    return;

}


function deleteListPhoneNumber(data) {


    WL.Logger.debug('Delete Data from JSONStore: ' + data);
    return;

}
```

This is my code in `main.js`:

```
$('#show-all-btn').on('click', showAllData);

var collectionName = 'Contacts',

collections = {};
collections[collectionName] = {
    searchFields: {
        name: 'string',
        number: 'string'
    },
    adapter: {
        name: 'listPhoneNumbers',
        add: 'addListPhoneNumber',
        replace: 'updateListPhoneNumber',
        remove: 'deleteListPhoneNumber',
        load: {
            procedure: 'getListPhoneNumbers',
            param: [],
            key: 'listContacts'
        }
    }
};

WL.JSONStore.init(collections)

    function showAllData() {

    $('#show-all-btn').on("click", function() {
        $('#info').show();
    });
    WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).load().then(function(res) {
        alert('ok' + JSON.stringify(res));
    }).fail(function(errorObject) {
        alert(errorObject);
    });
}
```

This is the error:

```
[wl.jsonstore] {"src":"load","err":18,"msg":"FAILED_TO_LOAD_INITIAL_DATA_FROM_ADAPTER_INVALID_L‌​OAD_OBJ","col":"Contact","usr":"jsonstore","doc":{},"res":{}
```

Comment: this is error: [wl.jsonstore] {"src":"load","err":18,"msg":"FAILED_TO_LOAD_INITIAL_DATA_FROM_ADAPTER_INVALID_LOAD_OBJ","col":"Contact","usr":"jsonstore","doc":{},"res":{}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is saying the load object you passed is invalid. This is probably because you passed `param` instead of `params`. Notice the `s` at the end.

Also, this code:

```
WL.JSONStore.init(collections)

    function showAllData() {

    $('#show-all-btn').on("click", function() {
        $('#info').show();
    });
    WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).load().then(function(res) {
        alert('ok' + JSON.stringify(res));
    }).fail(function(errorObject) {
        alert(errorObject);
    });
}
```

Looks wrong, maybe what you meant to write is something like this:

```
WL.JSONStore.init(collections).then(function () {

  WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).count().then(function (numberOfDocsInCollection) {
    if(numberOfDocsInCollection < 1) {
      WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).load().then(function(res) {
        //handle success
      })
    }
  })
});
```

I omitted handling failures for brevity. Note that the `load` will will duplicate items in the collection if those items already exist, hence the count to check if the collection is empty or not.